# How to integrate a fraction of the type $\frac{1}{(ax+b)^c(dx+e)^f}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm working on obtaining chemical reactions' speed, and this is one of the problems I met with.

$$ \int \frac{1}{(ax+b)^c(dx+e)^f}dx $$

Can this equation could be solved? If possible, please show the results.

Comment: Do you know anything about $c,f$?  Are they integers?  Positive?

Comment: In general, no. Wolfram alpha will return a hypergeometric function for the anti-derivative, but this is really just *naming* the integral as opposed to solving it.

Comment: @vadim123 c, f are positive numbers.

Comment: @ David H who write: <<In general, no. Wolfram alpha will return a hypergeometric function for the anti-derivative, but this is really just naming the integral as opposed to solving it>>. I don't agree at all ! For example, if the question was about $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ the answer would be $\ln(x)$, then is it just naming the integral as opposed to solving it ? Of course, the integral is named, but that is not all. Behind the name there is all the background on which you have access, as far as you know the name of the convenient special function.

Comment: To continue my comment : That is why the special functions are so usefull. A paper for general public on this topic : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Comment: @JJacquelin Interestingly, your tract, probably meant as a defense of special functions, nearly finishes with: "Pour aider à y voir plus clair dans tout ce bestiaire de fonctions, il faudrait songer à embaucher quelques naturalistes afin d'y mettre une certaine systématique. On attend les Jussieu, Darwin, Henning... des mathématiques." ...which (in the absence of the Jussieus, Darwins, etc., *of this special field* of mathematics) is exactly what DavidH's comment is pointing at.

Comment: @JJacquelin Prestige has nothing to do with it, the important fact is that the systematization work Darwin and others did, is not done with special functions (probably for good reasons), a fact which leads to the difference between *insight* and *naming* that DavidH mentioned. Oddly, you refuse this conclusion although you were led to state it clearly in your tract.

Comment: ((Comment by @JJacquelin now deleted.))

Comment: @Did : That is not exactly what I mean. The comment : <<to help seeing clearly in all this bestiary of functions, it would be necessary to think of hiring some naturalists in order to put to it a certain systematic. We expect in Mathematics prestigious scientists such as Jussieu, Darwin, Henning in Zoology: When the best-seller "Phylogenetic Classification of the Special Functions" will appear ? >> This only concerns the method of naming the special functions, not the use of them. A more logical method of naming would be the cherry on the cake, but it doesn't change the background.

Answer (score 4):

- If *c* and *f* are positive integers, evaluate $I(b,e)=\displaystyle\int\frac1{(ax+b)(dx+e)}dx$ in terms of *b* and 
   *e*, then differentiate the obtained result *c* times with regard to *b*, and *f* times with regard to *e*.

  ---
- If *c* and *f* are negative integers, let $t=ax+b$, for instance, then expand the other term using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), and switch the order of summation and integration.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, the result cannot be expressed as a combination of a limited number of elementary functions. The closed form involves a special function :
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+dx%2F%28%28%28ax%2Bb%29%5Ec%29%28%28Ax%2BB%29%5EC%29%29

In particular cases, for example if the powers are integers, or in other cases with particular values of the parameters, the special fuction reduces to fonctions of lower level, sometimes to elementary functions.

Comment: don't just post a link, actually show that this doesn't work.

Comment: @ Bot : Why do you say "this doesn't work" ? It works since the integral is expressed in term of Gauss hypergeometric function.That is the result. Do you expect that the formula with the hypergeometric function be explicitely written in my answer? But why asking for a copy of a formula that one can found thanks to the given link. Copying it should be just a waste of time. May be I didn't understand your remark ?

Comment: the question was Can this equation could be solved? If possible, please show the **results.** I think he wanted you to show work

Comment: Well, I will no longer discuss because it looks like a dialogue between deaf people ! Of course the equation can be solved and the result can be expressed thanks to hypergeometric function. No, I will not show the results because, it is a very small effort to see the results on the mathematical handbooks, while it should be a big effort without any usefulness to make a copy and post it on the forum. By the way, the question was raised by S.T.Kim and I would prefer that he discuss himself about what he exactly want than someone else.